# How to setup pngquant to Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I want to setup pngquant to my linux server but I don't know which ssh command should I use to setup it.

This library's web site is http://pngquant.org/ but there is no documentation about installing it to server via SSH

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release pngquant
```

Comment: Thanks! After running this command only `epel-release` was installed, so had to run another command to install `pngquant`.

Answer (score 5):

You should connect to your server via SSH, then download the sources (using `wget`) :

> wget https://github.com/pornel/pngquant/tarball/master

Then extract the downloaded tarball :

> tar xzf master

Then `cd` to whatever directory that created :

> cd ...

According to their [documentation](http://pngquant.org/install.html), you just need to `make` it :

> make

If that doesn't output any errors, you can install it system-wide by running `make install` as superuser (root) :

> sudo make install

Or, if sudo isn't available in your distribution :

> su root
>
> make install
>
> exit

And there you have it.

Comment: [root@server pornel-pngquant-d714336]# make install
gcc -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -I. -I../libpng -I../zlib -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/X11/include/ -DNDEBUG -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -ffinite-math-only -std=c99    -c -o pngquant.o pngquant.c I try both method but it outputs error every time.

Comment: Received this error too, however the important error line is `rwpng.h:35:57: error: png.h: No such file or directory`

To fix, you'll need to install `libpng-dev` or `libpng-devel` depending on your distribution. Worked perfectly for me after doing so.

Comment: Worked! but have in mind that in cases like mine, when using pngquant you need to be in the path it was installed, example:  
    `pngquant --quality 40-60 --force --verbose --output ../../path/to/save/image/my-logo-compressed.png ../../path/source/of/image/my-logo-uncompressed.png`
To use it from everywhere you could add an alias in ~/.bashrc, something like `alias pngquant="cd ~/my/path/to/pngquant/ && ./pngquant"` and then run `source .bashrc` to apply changes, but when using pngqunat you'll still need to put full paths to source and destination of images. Dont' know with PHP's shell_exec()